# deploying create-react-app to gh-pages

Tags: github-pages, create-react-app

This is well documented and I have followed the instructions very carefully several times over.
HOWEVER, every time I run the 'npm run deploy' command on a completely vanilla create-react-app install, it fails on my system with this error:-

> C:\React\weather-app>npm run deploy
>
> > weather-app@0.1.0 predeploy C:\React\weather-app
> >     npm run build
>
> npm WARN invalid config loglevel="notice"
>
> > weather-app@0.1.0 build C:\React\weather-app
> >     react-scripts build
>
> Creating an optimized production build... Compiled successfully.
>
> File sizes after gzip:
>
> 37.45 KB  build\static\js\main.9959b426.js   224 B     build\static\css\main.e94ed898.css
>
> The project was built assuming it is hosted at /weather-app/. You can
>   control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
>
> The build folder is ready to be deployed. To publish it at
>   https://my-github-username.github.io/weather-app, run:
>
> npm run deploy
>
> Find out more about deployment here:
>
> (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment)
>
> > weather-app@0.1.0 deploy C:\React\weather-app
> >     gh-pages -d build
>
> error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory fatal: unable to
>   fork
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! weather-app@0.1.0
>   deploy: `gh-pages -d build` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
>   Failed at the weather-app@0.1.0 deploy script. npm ERR! This is
>   probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-07-31T16_10_08_763Z-debug.log

This is driving me insane, PLEASE can anyone give me any pointers as to what's wrong with my local node, to prevent this script from running?

Comment: I have the same problem...

Comment: Check out the official doc https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem! But I think I found a work around at least for the time being...

1. Make a production build with either `npm run build` or a failed `npm run deploy`
2. Then run gh-page's script that was supposed to run `gh-pages -d build`

Good luck!